# CiviCRM CiviMail Images are relative URLs

Tags: civicrm

When using the CiviMail WYSIWYG to compose a mailing, clicking the image insert option and then choosing "browse server", then uploading an image and inserting it - results in a broken image in the sent email because it uses a relative URL for the image.

Given that this is CiviMail and its sole purpose is to send out mailings, it seems like this behavior should be gleaned and replaced prior to sending? Is there an extension or way to configure it to fix this? I recall this being an issue previously, but had thought this was resolved for 4.5. Anyone know if there is a way to configure without jumping into the wysiwyg's direct code and overriding?

Answer (score 3):

1. the editor is used in multiple locations besides civimail
2. Might want to check see if the wysiwyg editor has a setting that decides between relative vs absolute urls. might want to tweak that setting and see if it fixes things